# Spring Security - Authenticate RESTful Resource using OAUTH maintaining true STATELESS access

Tags: spring, security, rest, oauth

I have done a lot of research on this topic - "Authenticate RESTful Resource using OAUTH maintaining true STATELESS nature between Client-Server". From what it looks like - it's not possible.

I wonder if what I think is correct or there's someway to achieve this somehow.

Since OAUTH involves a 3rd party Service Provider, I am sure user won't like to enter username/password each time a request is sent to the server. Perhaps there's a way by storing some cookie or something on the client side to detect if user is logged-in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is not (practically) possible. The only alternative that I've found is to go through the authentication process for every single request from a given client, which is as you pointed out is completely impractical.  I consider the stateless "requirement" of REST architecture to include 'business data': session attributes and other contextual data / flags / caches related to the resources you are serving and not authentication / authorization details.